# Edit HTML code Of a form before submiting and save entered values

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this html form :

```
<form role="form"  id="testForm" action="/lancerTest" method=post>

                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-warning">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
                    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btntest">Lancer le test</button>
                </form>
```

I want to perform some actions before submiting this form so I used the following code:

```
 $('#testForm').submit(function() {
$('#loading').show();
var htmlOutput = $('#testForm').html();

newcontnent="<fieldset disabled>"+htmlOutput+"</fieldset>";
$('#testForm').html(newcontnent);


    return true; 
});
```

But when submiting this form, all entered values have been lost  (I think, because I edited the html code of the form before submiting).
so, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: because you are overwriting the html, so values are being lost.

Comment: The form is submited so a refresh/redirect is done on the actual page. So anyway, current values would be lose. Can you provide concrete sample of your expected behaviour?

Comment: Is expected result for `form` to be disabled after submission? Note, `.html()` returns `.innerHTML` content of `form`, does not include `<form>` `.outerHTML`

Comment: @A.Wolff :
When I submit the form, I perform some actions in the server which takes a lot of time, so I want to disable all inputs while waiting for the server response

Comment: @Massi You could just use `$('#testForm :input').prop('disabled', true);` to disable all inputs inside form.

Comment: @A.Wolff I have exactly the same problem when trying your code. All entered values have been lost in the post request

Comment: Oh ya, disabled inputs arent send to server.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `click` event, prevent default action, do your stuff, then submit the form:

```
$('#your-submit-button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // your stuff

    $('#your-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem when I tried your code

Answer (score 0):

delete type="submit" from button

```
   $('#btntest').click(function () {

 // your treatment

  var inputSuccess=$('#inputSuccess').val(); 
  var inputWarning=$('#inputWarning').val();
  var inputError=$('#inputError').val();

 // you can send data with post method

 $.post('url_page.php',{inputSuccess:inputSuccess,inputWarning:inputWarning,
  inputError:inputError},function(){

});

});
```

Comment: Missing `,` after url at `$.post()`. `form` would still be submitted?

Comment: I my real form, I have a lot of inputs , chekboxes ..., so, is this the only way to save entered values ?

Comment: you want to save data from input or from php variables?

Comment: From inputs and chekboxes